# Emulation of the Raspberry Pi with sensors

Tags: sensor, emulation

I am trying to emulate NOOBS or some other Raspberry Pi distro.
I have tried QEMU but unfortunately this does not simulate peripheral devices (eg. Sensors)
I was wondering if it was possible that a emulator could simulate the sensors as well, for some python code that needs running.

BTW.
I am using a Mac environment

Comment: What you want is beyond emulation of a RPi. You want a simulation of peripheral devices on top of that. To have that work with just any generic sensor this simulator has to be pretty powerful. Can you not just work around that on application level, e.g. write testing modules that feed "simulated" sensor data?

Answer (score 1):

It is not reasonably possible to perfectly emulate sensor physics, you can emulate the the communication to digital sensors however it's rather pointless so you will have to write your own sensor simulator as I doubt anyone else has for your selected sensor among the many.